# How to Optimize this query where data is retrieved from View

Tags: sql-server

I'm using the following query retrieve some data but it's taking around 1 min 30 sec
to get data. Can I optimize it anyhow 
Here vOrderDetail is a View

```
SELECT VORD.[OrderType] AS [OrderType],SUM(ISNULL(VORD.[Balance],0)) TotalPayment,
SUM(ISNULL(VORD.[PaidPayment],0)) PaymentReceived,SUM(ISNULL(VORD.[Balance],0) - ISNULL(VORD.[PaidPayment],0)) AS PaymentLeft
FROM vOrderDetail VORD
INNER JOIN Orders ORD  ON ORD.Id=VORD.[OrderId]
WHERE ORD.SellerId = 1 AND VORD.[OrderDate]>='2019-05-01 00:00:00.000' AND VORD.[OrderDate]<'2019-06-01 00:00:00.000' 
GROUP BY VORD.[OrderType]
```

Comment: Show us your execution plan.

Comment: Check your `where` conditions. You should order the `and` conditions, setting the more restrictive first

Comment: More often than not performance is down to proper indexing. Is there an index on Orders.SellerId? How about the OrderDate column underlying the view. Can you show us the view code @aperezfals the order of the AND conditions will not affect the execution plan - the optimizer will look at all of them and make its own decision about the best way to apply them. This is in SQL Server at least, I can't say for other RDBMS. (Happy to be proven wrong, show me an example)

Answer (score 0):

Try This way :

```
SELECT 
    VORD.[OrderType] AS [OrderType], 
    SUM(
        ISNULL(VORD.[Balance], 0)
        ) TotalPayment, 
    SUM(
        ISNULL(VORD.[PaidPayment], 0)
        ) PaymentReceived, 
    SUM(
        ISNULL(VORD.[Balance], 0) - ISNULL(VORD.[PaidPayment], 0)
    ) AS PaymentLeft 
    FROM vOrderDetail VORD 
        WHERE EXISTS
            (
                SELECT
                    1
                    FROM Orders
                        WHERE SellerId = 1
                            AND Id = VORD.[OrderId] 
            )
        AND CAST(VINS.[OrderDate] AS DATE) = CAST('2019-05-01' AS DATE)
        GROUP BY 
            VORD.[OrderType]
```

I replaced the Join with Exists since you are not using any columns of the join anywhere and changed the between check with =